# Getting an error in a script

Tags: javascript, syntax

Hi I am making a script for a gambling website. I Keep getting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" but I check through lint and other things and it still doesn't find it.

http://pastebin.com/qyMhXGWk is my script.

Comment: Unexpected token where? You don't expect us to debug that whole file, now.

Comment: Are you kidding me??? You can't even be bothered to paste the source code with the problem.  Seriously read the FAQ about asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

The } at lines 204 and 175 doesn't seem to be needed I recommend  deleting it and retrying the script. I would also recommend using some form of text editor like notepad++